# Graph of the function (2x^2-2)/(x^2-1)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am learning precalculus and my precalculus book gives this equation:

[image: equation 1]

for this graph:

[image: graph]

But when I enter that equation into some online graph tool like Symbolab ( https://www.symbolab.com/graphing-calculator ) I get this graph:

[image: graph from symbolab]

It seems that (many) online calculators cancel (x+1)(x-1) in numerator/denominator before drawing a graph.

So, which graph of those 2 is "correct"? Why?

P.S. My previous question was downvoted and removed as "not interesting for math community". That was very rude having in mind that I am beginner, looking for a help. Perhaps I should join some other forum for math beginners but I don't know which and where?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The given diagram appears to be a graph of the [function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/czntdro6la)
$$g(x)=\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2-1}$$
Although the supplied function is
$$f(x)=\frac{2(x^2-1)}{x^2-1}=2\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$$
so the second diagram is correct.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ equals $-1$ or $1$, $\frac{2x^2-2}{x^2-1}$ does not exist.  Otherwise, it is perfectly fine to divide top and bottom by $x^2-1$.  That yields the second graph: $y=2$ with gaps at $x=\pm1$.

I will second Peter Foreman's guess at the function of $\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2-1}$.  The first graph appears to have asymptotes at $x=\pm1$ and $y=2$.  $\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2-1}=2+\frac1{x^2-1}$ can get close to $2$ without ever equaling it and is equal to $1$ at $x=0$.

Comment: `If  does not equal −1 or 1, the fraction does not exist` Don't you mean that the fraction does not exist if x DOES equal -1 or 1?

Comment: @numbermaniac oops.  Easy fix.